# C# Using SoundPlayer to Pause and Resume

Tags: c#, audio

I am another person dabbling with C# and wanting to create a simple audio application that plays wav files loaded into the program via an upload program. My issue is that I need to get whatever audio file currently being played to pause with the track timer of the audio file being used when I start the audio file again via my Play button. I already have a global timer, 'baseTimer', that I think I can use to set the audio file, that was stopped, track duration point. However I do not know how to accomplish this nor do I really know how to use all of the mci commands yet.

I have displayed all of my code for my main application... I also have read that I may need to utilize threading, but I've also read that it would be impossible to set an audio files track duration with a thread.

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    System.Timers.Timer baseTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    List<string> PlayList = new List<string>();
    List<byte> PlayList_byte;
    int soundNum = 0;

    private string music_PATH { get; set; }
    private string talk_PATH { get; set; }
    private byte Pause_TIME { get; set; }
    private string Pause_RADIO { get; set; }

    bool isStopped = new bool();
    bool isPaused = new bool();

    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern uint mciSendString(string command, StringBuilder returnValue, int returnLength, IntPtr winHandle);

    public static int GetSoundLength(string fileName)
    {
        StringBuilder lengthBuf = new StringBuilder(32);

        mciSendString(string.Format("open \"{0}\" type waveaudio alias wave", fileName), null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        mciSendString("status wave length", lengthBuf, lengthBuf.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);
        mciSendString("close wave", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        int length = 0;
        int.TryParse(lengthBuf.ToString(), out length);

        return length;
    }

    private void SetPath()
    {
        music_PATH = @"..\\..\\commercial\list.txt";
        talk_PATH = @"..\\..\\main\list.txt";
        StreamReader myReader;

        using (myReader = new StreamReader(music_PATH))
        {
            while (myReader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                string read = myReader.ReadLine();
                PlayList.Add(read);
            }
        }

        using (myReader = new StreamReader(talk_PATH))
        {
            while (myReader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                string read = myReader.ReadLine();
                PlayList.Add(read);
            }
            myReader.Close();
        }

        foreach (string sound in PlayList)
        {
            soundNum++;
        }
    }

    private string CurrentSound()
    {
        try
        {
            Random _randx = new Random();
            int pick = _randx.Next(0, soundNum);

            string currentaudio = PlayList[pick];
            Pause_RADIO = currentaudio;
            return currentaudio;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    string _SelectedSound = "";

    private string _Sound(string currentradio, string pattern)
    {
        foreach (Match entry in Regex.Matches(currentradio, pattern))
        {
            _SelectedSound = entry.Value.ToString();
        }
        if (_SelectedSound == "music")
        {
            return "commercial";
        }
        else if (_SelectedSound == "talk")
        {
            return "main";
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void _SetTimer(string currentradio, string pattern)
    {
        baseTimer.Interval = GetSoundLength(@"..\\..\\" + pattern + @"\" + currentradio);
    }

    private bool isRepeat(string lastradio, string currentradio)
    {
        if (lastradio == currentradio)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void baseTimerElasped(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Radio.FrmMain play = new Radio.FrmMain();
        play.PlayPlayer();
    }

    private void PlayPlayer()
    {
        MediaPlayer wavplayer;
        try
        {
            if (soundNum == 0)
            {
                SetPath();
                PlayPlayer();
            }
            else
            {
                string currentradio = CurrentSound();
                bool localcheck = isRepeat(_SelectedSound, currentradio);
                if (localcheck == true)
                {
                    PlayPlayer();
                }
                else
                {
                    string Pattern = @"(music|talk)";
                    string selected = _Sound(currentradio, Pattern);
                    _SetTimer(currentradio, selected);

                    switch (selected)
                    {
                        case "commercial":
                            music_PATH = @"..\\..\\commercial\";
                            PlayList_byte = new List<byte>(File.ReadAllBytes(music_PATH + currentradio));
                            wavplayer = new MediaPlayer(PlayList_byte.GetRange(0, PlayList_byte.Count).ToArray());
                            wavplayer.Play();
                            baseTimer.Start();
                            break;
                        case "main":
                            talk_PATH = @"..\\..\\main\";
                            PlayList_byte = new List<byte>(File.ReadAllBytes(talk_PATH + currentradio));
                            wavplayer = new MediaPlayer(PlayList_byte.GetRange(0, PlayList_byte.Count).ToArray());
                            wavplayer.Play();
                            baseTimer.Start();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.Source);
        }
    }

    private void PausePlayer()
    {
        MediaPlayer wavplayer = new MediaPlayer(PlayList_byte.GetRange(0, PlayList_byte.Count).ToArray());
        baseTimer.Stop();

        MessageBox.Show("Count: " + PlayList_byte.Count + "Pause_TIME: " + Pause_TIME + "\nPlaylist_byte" + PlayList_byte.ToString());

        try
        {
            switch (isPaused)
            {
                case false:
                    isPaused = true;
                    wavplayer.Stop();
                    break;
                case true:
                    isPaused = false;
                    string localcheck = _Sound(Pause_RADIO, @"(music|talk)");
                    switch (localcheck)
                    {
                        case "commercial":
                            music_PATH = @"..\\..\\commercial\";
                            wavplayer.Play(PlayList_byte.GetRange(PlayList_byte.Count - Pause_TIME, PlayList_byte.Count - Pause_TIME).ToArray());
                            break;
                        case "main":
                            talk_PATH = @"..\\..\\main\";
                            wavplayer.Play(PlayList_byte.GetRange(PlayList_byte.Count - Pause_TIME, PlayList_byte.Count - Pause_TIME).ToArray());
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message + ex.Data);
        }
    }

    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (isStopped)
        {
            case false:
                isStopped = true;
                btnPlay.Image = Image.FromFile(@"..\\..\\Pause.png");
                lblPlay.Text = "Pause";
                if (isPaused == false)
                {
                    PlayPlayer();
                }
                else
                {
                    PausePlayer();
                }
                break;
            case true:
                isStopped = false;
                btnPlay.Image = Image.FromFile(@"..\\..\\Play.png");
                lblPlay.Text = "Play";
                PausePlayer();
                break;
        }

        baseTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(baseTimerElasped);
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlayPlayer();
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MediaPlayer wavplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        wavplayer.Stop();
        baseTimer.Stop();
    }

    private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void btnGetUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uploader FrmUpload = new Uploader();
        FrmUpload.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
class MediaPlayer
{
    SoundPlayer wavplayer;

    public MediaPlayer()
    {
        Stop();
    }

    public MediaPlayer(byte[] buffer)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, true);
        wavplayer = new SoundPlayer(memStream);
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        wavplayer.Play();
    }

    public void Play(byte[] buffer)
    {
        wavplayer.Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        wavplayer.Stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        wavplayer.Play();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        wavplayer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Edit:

For clarity currentaudio has a file as such "music3.wav" or "talk1.wav" in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super old question but just for anyone looking here's what worked for me:

```
double currentPos = audioplayer.CurrentPosition;
audioplayer.Play();
audioplayer.Seek(currentPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

[SoundPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) is extremely limited, and doesn't support Pause and Resume. Are you able to use the WPF [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead? You will find it is much more powerful, supporting playing files of many types, repositioning, setting volume, pausing and resuming. You can also use it to get the file length instead of mci.

Comment: So there is not a way to use mci to push the status wave length into my application with any .wav file I want?