# how to pause and resume audio in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, audio

I am working on wpf application. I want to pause and resume audio but the song is playing from the beginning.

```
//c# code

System.Media.SoundPlayer sp = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"D:\Intro.wav");
private void play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    sp.Play();
    play_btn.Enabled = false;
    stop_btn.Enabled = true; 
}

private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    sp.Stop();
    stop_btn.Enabled = false;
    play_btn.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Was asked [before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19762734/1997232).

Comment: But not answered satisfactorily, and so still needs an answer.

Comment: @goobering, it was answered, but answer was simply not accepted (happens often). My comment is a diplomatic way of saying "use search".

Comment: The SoundPlayer API does not support pausing. Have you tried manipulating the Stream object instead? If using MediaElement is not an option for you, please add that to the question. The way the question is formatted now it's a duplicate, because the linked question does have an answer using a different API.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement` instead of `System.Media.SoundPlayer`. It has a `Pause` function.

```
<Grid> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <RowDefinition Height="320*"/> 
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer" Grid.RowSpan="1" LoadedBehavior="Manual"/> 
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"> 
        <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Content="Play" Click="btnPlay_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/> 
        <Button x:Name="btnStop" Content="Stop" Click="btnStop_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/> 
        <Button x:Name="btnMoveBack" Content="Back" Click="btnMoveBack_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/> 
        <Button x:Name="btnMoveForward" Content="Forward" Click="btnMoveForward_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/> 
    </StackPanel> 
</Grid>

private void IsPlaying(bool flag) 
{ 
    btnPlay.IsEnabled = flag; 
    btnStop.IsEnabled = flag; 
    btnMoveBack.IsEnabled = flag; 
    btnMoveForward.IsEnabled = flag; 
} 

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    IsPlaying(true); 
    if (btnPlay.Content.ToString() == "Play") 
    { 
        MediaPlayer.Play(); 
        btnPlay.Content = "Pause"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        MediaPlayer.Pause(); 
        btnPlay.Content = "Play"; 
    } 
} 

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MediaPlayer.Pause(); 
    btnPlay.Content = "Play"; 
    IsPlaying(false); 
    btnPlay.IsEnabled = true; 
} 

private void btnMoveBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MediaPlayer.Position -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); 
} 

private void btnMoveForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MediaPlayer.Position += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); 
}
```

Comment: Code is more probably taken from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-Use-Media-Element-b8ce7e92).

Answer (score 0):

The Soundplayer doesn't support Pause and Resume. You could use the WPF MediaElement instead.

If you MUST use the Soundplayer you could start a new thread with the muted song every second. After that you have to mute the loud one in the Pause Method. In the Resume Method you'll have to check which thread is at the best time.

But i think this would be the most horrible solution.

Cheers

Comment: That would be a horrific solution. If the audio track was 10 minutes long you would end up with 36000 threads!!