# Play Music before and after another Sound runs, starting at the point it stopped

Tags: c#, winforms, audio

I'm currently doing an Options menu for my small game. The menu has the ability, for example, to enable Music and Sounds.

If you enable the Music, and the Sounds, the following happens:

1. Play the Music
2. If you win, play a win Sound
3. Silence.

What *should* happen: 
1. Play Music
2. Start the Sound if you won
3. Play the Music from where it stopped

For now, I check if a Checkbox is checked, and if so, play the Music:

```
else if (enable_music.Checked && enable_sound.Checked && download_no)
        {
            //Store the State of the Application
            Properties.Settings.Default.enable_music = true;
            Properties.Settings.Default.enable_sounds = true;
            //Load Music
            SoundPlayer snd = new SoundPlayer(fileName_standard);
            //We need to call the Sound only if we won or lost, so we save the Preference and call it in the Winscreen
            Properties.Settings.Default.enable_sounds = true;
            //Play the files
            snd.Play();
            Close();
        }
```

The winning Sound only get's played if the Winscreen is shown.

So I thought about putting the music into a new method, and call it later:

```
private async Task PlayMusic(SoundPlayer snd)
    {
        snd.Play();
    }
```

call:

```
else if(enable_darkmode.Checked && download_no)
        {
            SoundPlayer snd= new SoundPlayer(fileName_dark);
            PlayMusic(snd);
            Close();
        }
```

But still, if the other file starts to play, the normal Music stops. 
So how do I get the Music to pause if another file is playing, and resume it if the file stopped playing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use seperate threads to run seperate instances of the music playing and therefore the orugunal can pause while the second runs without inturupting the paused audio

Comment: But how to pause the sound? As far as I can tell there is no `music.Pause()` option

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762734/c-sharp-using-soundplayer-to-pause-and-resume